# How to manage Portrait and Landscape images in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am developing app for ipad, Portrait images are working fine but when i switch to landscape its massed up the screen, Is there any way to manage both images or auto adjustment.

Comment: Hi adam,there are two options for managing this either use two images one for portrait and one for landscape of use aspectFit property of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

in .m file do things according to current orientation

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

-(void)orientationChanged {


    UIDeviceOrientation   orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
               //for iphone 5 LandscapeLeft
            } else {
               //for iphone 4 LandscapeLeft
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //for ipad LandscapeLeft
        }

    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
                // for iphone 5 LandscapeRight
            } else {
               // for iphone 4 LandscapeRight
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //for ipad LandscapeRight
        }


    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        //do change in design when ios change
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {

                // for iphone 5 Portrait
            } else {
                // for iphone 4 Portrait
            }
        } else {
            //for ipad Portrait
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //Do what you want in Portrait Upside Down
      if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
                // for iphone 5 PortraitUpsideDown

            } else {
              // for iphone 4 PortraitUpsideDown  
            }
        } else {
            //for ipad PortraitUpsideDown
        }
    }
}
```

`orientationChanged` method called whenever your divice change orientation. than you can set image according to your new orientation. and yes you have to create your image for two orientation portrait and landscap.

Answer (score 0):

There are options :-

1) if ios 6 you can use autolayout .
2) you can set frames for the uicontrols separately  and use these two methods if ios 6

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ;//return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and after this whereever required like in ViewDidlOAd() and viewWillAppear()
do this

```
 if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication ]statusBarOrientation))
{
// change frames
}
else
{
// for landscape change frames here
}
```

iOS < 6.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation // Deprecated in iOS 6.x 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```